# Error executing conditional statement in repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, repeater, conditional-operator

I am trying to execute following conditional code in a repeater:

```
<%# new MAINLIB.DbaseOps(null).getImage(Eval("desid").ToString())!=null?Response.Write("<img src='" + new MAINLIB.DbaseOps(null).getImage(Eval("desid").ToString()) + "' alt='" + Eval("title").ToString().Substring(0, 20) + "' />") : Response.Write("") %>
```

**Code Explanation:**

1. MAINLIB.DbaseOps(null).getImage() return image path as string related to "desid" (Description ID). The function is working well and good on other pages.
2. The motive is to check if image for a "desid" exists then add an `img` tag else add blank or null string on aspx page.

But its giving following compile time error on the same line.

> Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is
>   no implicit conversion between 'void' and 'void

Please tell me the solution to this?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are using `Response.Write` at all here? As far as I know, this is not needed on a binding expression.

Comment: Hey actually its now working. I forgot about that we don't need to use Response.Write in binding expression. @Oded add your this suggestion as an answer, I will mark it. So that it may help those who done the same mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use `Response.Write` inside a binding expression.

Remove that and you should be OK.